# Connect hawtio in chrome to Karaf

Tags: google-chrome, apache-karaf, hawtio

I hava just installed the hawtio chrome extension.
It works pretty good.
Now, I just want to connect to a local Apache Karaf.
In the connection settings, I have this values :

```
Connection name : Karaf_local
Scheme : http
Host : localhost
Port : 8040
Path : jolokia
User name : karaf
Password : my_karaf_password
```

I don't know what Path means here...
Of course, Jolokia agent is running in my local karaf.

Comment: have you installed jolokia in your karaf container? The url is likely more 8181/jolokia as port 8181 is the default karaf http port

Answer (score 0):

The path is usualy 'jolokia' (as in `http://localhost:8040/jolokia`)